# How to convert .php.html to csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following url

http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/crests.php?wfo=lch&gage=bsll1&crest_type=historic

and want to convert this into csv or in any tabular form

Comment: What you tried to achieve this? Do you want us to code it for you?

Comment: Do an http call, pull the data down, write it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and lxml:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
import string


# download response
response = requests.get('http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/crests.php?wfo=lch&gage=bsll1&crest_type=historic')
html = response.text
```

You now have the raw html text. You need to strip this of tags. Here we use lxml, a python library to process HTML/XML text. The fromstring() function is used to parse strings into elements.

```
#clean up
doc = fromstring(html)
tags = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6',
               'div', 'span', 
                      'img', 'area', 'map']
args = {'meta':False, 'safe_attrs_only':False, 'page_structure':False, 
               'scripts':True, 'style':True, 'links':True, 'remove_tags':tags}
```

Identify the tags to be removed. The Cleaner class cleans the html document of the offending tags - so we create a cleaner object, passing a list of the class variables to be blacklisted (along with the tags to be removed). See [lxml Cleaner class documentation](http://lxml.de/3.6/lxmldoc-3.6.4.pdf) for what each attribute is set to by default. Note that `remove_tags` only strips the tags, and not the content.

```
cleaner = Cleaner(**args)
path = '/html/body'
body = doc.xpath(path)[0] #only interested in the body of the response
clean_response = cleaner.clean_html(body).text_content() #clean!

# split into lines.
table = clean_response.splitlines()

#parse whichever way you wish to
#your code here
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain most of this is far from 'self explanatory' for someone not already well versed in lxml.

Comment: have used the split function in the output file and now i want to give column name to the splitted data like date for 05/20/1953 and height for 34.39. as in dictionaries: Date and Height is the key. I hope I am able to state my question well

Answer (score 2):

The process of extracting data from websites is called [webscraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

This piece of code that may help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/crests.php?wfo=lch&gage=bsll1&crest_type=historic'
#read html page using urlopen() method
r = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

#create soup to navigate through tags
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

#find the data inside the div mark, under the water_information class tag
results = soup.find('div', {'class':'water_information'})

#get only text from the results soup
water_data = results.text

#write this info to an output file
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(water_data)
```

This is a sample of the content of my `outputfile.txt`:

```
Historic Crests
(1) 34.39 ft on 05/20/1953
(2) 31.74 ft on 02/07/1955
(3) 31.08 ft on 08/11/1940
(4) 30.65 ft on 11/01/1985
(5) 29.59 ft on 04/14/1995
(6) 26.99 ft on 07/04/1989
(7) 26.46 ft on 09/23/1979
(8) 26.22 ft on 12/30/1982
(9) 26.10 ft on 10/31/2002
(10) 26.06 ft on 01/13/2013
```

Now you can easily work with the `water_data` string by using `regex` and `split()`, to create your own CSV file.

You didn't thought I would write it all for you, right? `:P`

Comment: I have used the split function in the output file and now i want to give column name to the splitted data like date for 05/20/1953 and height for 34.39. as in dictionaries: Date and Height is the key. I hope I am able to state my question well